# PHP code to delete all duplicate records except One in MySQL database table

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have a database table having records more then 300,000 companies.

Each record have phone number.
I want to keep just one record from duplicate records.

for example:

| id | Title | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Company 01 | 111 111 11 |
| 2 | Company 02 | 222 222 22 |
| 3 | Company 03 | 333 333 33 |
| 4 | Company 04 | 444 444 44 |
| 5 | Company 05 | 333 333 33 |
| 6 | Company 06 | 555 555 55 |
| 7 | Company 07 | 222 222 22 |
| 8 | Company 08 | 333 333 33 |
| 9 | Company 09 | 666 666 66 |

I want to keep any one record from id (2, 7) and one record from id (3, 5, 8)

I can find duplicate record by GROUP BY query, but not sure how to delete except one.

This is what I am doing

```
<?php
$qry    = "SELECT phone, COUNT(*) as total FROM companies GROUP BY phone HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"
$result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $qry);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
{
    // here should be code to keep one record
    
    // here is code to delete duplicate records
    $qry_del    = "DELETE from companies where phone = '".$row['phone']."'";
    mysqli_query($dbConn, $qry_del);
}
?>
```

Comment: You could put something like SELECT MIN(id) AS minid, phone...etc in your select query, then add AND id > $row['minid'] to the DELETE query. If phone column isn't indexed, this approach could be pretty inefficient.

Comment: ...assuming ids are unique of course.

Comment: Your example "duplicates" have different company values. You didn't say what your criteria for deletion/retention are.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If performance and duration are not that important, you could select companies by their phone number and then delete them by their identifier.

Perhaps the following script will help you:

```
$qry    = "SELECT phone, COUNT(*) as total FROM companies GROUP BY phone HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";

$result = mysqli_query($dbConn, $qry);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    // temporary storage for the companies IDs which should deleted
    $recordsToDelete = [];

    // counter that controls how many records are to be deleted
    $maxCountToDelete = $row['total'] - 1;

    // get all companies with specific phone number
    $selectCompanies    = "SELECT id FROM companies WHERE phone = '". $dbConn->real_escape_string( $row['phone'] ) ."'";
    $resultCompanies = mysqli_query($dbConn, $selectCompanies);

    // collect the ids
    $i= 0;
    while($rowCompanie = mysqli_fetch_array($resultCompanies ))
    {
        if( $i < $maxCountToDelete){
            $recordsToDelete[] = $rowCompanie['id'];
        }

        $i++;
    }

    // delete the companies in one SQL statment
    $qryDel    = "DELETE FROM companies WHERE id IN  (". $dbConn->real_escape_string( implode(',', $recordsToDelete) ) .") ";
    

    mysqli_query($dbConn, $qryDel );
}
```

Please note that "*maxCountToDelete*" only works because your delete condition is that you want to select companies by their phones, regardless of whether the company name is different

Comment: There's no need for two SELECTs.

Comment: You are absolutely right, but maybe my solution is easier to understand for a not so experienced developer. That is the reason why I posted it.